# Magento 2.3 call api rest extern

Tags: magento2.3, api, rest-api

I created a Magento 2.0 module and it calls an external web service with the command `\Zend_XmlRpc_Client`.

```
/* REST */
$client = new \Zend_XmlRpc_Client($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('akria_store/store_view/domain_configurateur').'/api/xmlrpc/');
$session = $client->call('login', array($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('akria_store/soap/user'), $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('akria_store/soap/password')));
$result = $client->call('call', array   ($session, 'configurateur_api.setprojectstate' ,array(array('order_id'=>$order_id,'state' => \Akria\Configurateur\Model\Project::PENDING,'project' => $item->getData('configurateur_project_id')))));
```

But this function no longer exists.

How can I now call an **external web service** without using **curl**? replacement function of `\Zend_XmlRpc_Client`.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP:

use Magento\Framework\Webapi\Soap\Client

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Soap\ClientFactory $soap
) {
    $this->soap = $soap;
}
```

and in function

```
public function makeRequest() {
     $opts = [
                'http' => [
                    'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
                ]
            ];
     $context = stream_context_create($opts);
     $url = 'http://someurl.com';
     $soapClientOptions = [
                'stream_context' => $context,
                'cache_wsdl' => 0
            ];
     $client = $this->soap->create($url, $soapClientOptions);
     $content = ['test' => '123'];
     $result = $client->functionFromApi($options);
}
```

Curl:

Use `Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl` class.

There are some functions for set headers, credentials, body etc.

To make request just create object:

```
public function construct(
    Curl $curl,
) {
    $this->curl = $curl;
}
```

and in function

```
public function makeRequest() {
    $url = 'http://someurl.com';
    $content = ['test' => '123'];

    //to make post request
    $this->curl->post($url, $content);

    //to make get request
    $this->curl->get($url, $content);

    //to get response from request
    $response = $this->curl->getBody();
}
```

Comment: Thx, use curl I find it very ugly so I'm going to use SOAP